# how to use multi-texture as one texture?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to use glues(the function is following) to draw sphere, which only support a single texture.
And I have to use a big texture(8096X4096) on iphone4. I split the big texture into several small ones(512X512). How can I use multi-texture to combine these small ones to be a big one to pass to gluSphere to use????

Thank you in advance!

```
   //glues draw sphere function
GLAPI void APIENTRY gluSphere(GLUquadric* qobj, GLfloat radius, GLint slices, GLint stacks)
            {
               GLint i, j;
               GLfloat sinCache1a[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat cosCache1a[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat sinCache2a[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat cosCache2a[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat sinCache3a[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat cosCache3a[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat sinCache1b[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat cosCache1b[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat sinCache2b[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat cosCache2b[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat sinCache3b[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat cosCache3b[CACHE_SIZE];
               GLfloat angle;
               GLfloat zLow, zHigh;
               GLfloat sintemp1 = 0.0, sintemp2 = 0.0, sintemp3 = 0.0, sintemp4 = 0.0;
               GLfloat costemp1 = 0.0, costemp2 = 0.0, costemp3 = 0.0, costemp4 = 0.0;
               GLfloat vertices[(CACHE_SIZE+1)*2][3];
               GLfloat texcoords[(CACHE_SIZE+1)*2][2];
               GLfloat normals[(CACHE_SIZE+1)*2][3];
               GLboolean needCache2, needCache3;
               GLint start, finish;
               GLboolean texcoord_enabled;
               GLboolean normal_enabled;
               GLboolean vertex_enabled;
               GLboolean color_enabled;

               if (slices>=CACHE_SIZE)
               {
                  slices=CACHE_SIZE-1;
               }

               if (stacks>=CACHE_SIZE)
               {
                  stacks=CACHE_SIZE-1;
               }

               if (slices<2 || stacks<1 || radius<0.0)
               {
                  gluQuadricError(qobj, GLU_INVALID_VALUE);
                  return;
               }

               /* Cache is the vertex locations cache */
               /* Cache2 is the various normals at the vertices themselves */
               /* Cache3 is the various normals for the faces */
               needCache2=needCache3=GL_FALSE;

               if (qobj->normals==GLU_SMOOTH)
               {
                  needCache2=GL_TRUE;
               }

               if (qobj->normals==GLU_FLAT)
               {
                  if (qobj->drawStyle!=GLU_POINT)
                  {
                     needCache3=GL_TRUE;
                  }
                  if (qobj->drawStyle==GLU_LINE)
                  {
                     needCache2=GL_TRUE;
                  }
               }

               for (i=0; i<slices; i++)
               {
                  angle=2.0f*PI*i/slices;
                  sinCache1a[i]=(GLfloat)sin(angle);
                  cosCache1a[i]=(GLfloat)cos(angle);
                  if (needCache2)
                  {
                     sinCache2a[i] = sinCache1a[i];
                     cosCache2a[i] = cosCache1a[i];
                  }
               }

               for (j=0; j<=stacks; j++)
               {
                  angle=PI*j/stacks;
                  if (needCache2)
                  {
                     if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                     {
                        sinCache2b[j]=(GLfloat)sin(angle);
                        cosCache2b[j]=(GLfloat)cos(angle);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        sinCache2b[j]=(GLfloat)-sin(angle);
                        cosCache2b[j]=(GLfloat)-cos(angle);
                     }
                  }

                  sinCache1b[j]=(GLfloat)(radius*sin(angle));
                  cosCache1b[j]=(GLfloat)(radius*cos(angle));
               }

               /* Make sure it comes to a point */
               sinCache1b[0]=0;
               sinCache1b[stacks]=0;

               if (needCache3)
               {
                  for (i=0; i<slices; i++)
                  {
                     angle=2.0f*PI*(i-0.5f)/slices;
                     sinCache3a[i]=(GLfloat)sin(angle);
                     cosCache3a[i]=(GLfloat)cos(angle);
                  }
                  for (j=0; j<=stacks; j++)
                  {
                     angle=PI*(j-0.5f)/stacks;
                     if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                     {
                        sinCache3b[j]=(GLfloat)sin(angle);
                        cosCache3b[j]=(GLfloat)cos(angle);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        sinCache3b[j]=(GLfloat)-sin(angle);
                        cosCache3b[j]=(GLfloat)-cos(angle);
                     }
                  }
               }

               sinCache1a[slices]=sinCache1a[0];
               cosCache1a[slices]=cosCache1a[0];
               if (needCache2)
               {
                  sinCache2a[slices]=sinCache2a[0];
                  cosCache2a[slices]=cosCache2a[0];
               }
               if (needCache3)
               {
                  sinCache3a[slices]=sinCache3a[0];
                  cosCache3a[slices]=cosCache3a[0];
               }

               /* Store status of enabled arrays */
               texcoord_enabled=GL_FALSE; //glIsEnabled(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
               normal_enabled=GL_FALSE; //glIsEnabled(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
               vertex_enabled=GL_FALSE; //glIsEnabled(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
               color_enabled=GL_FALSE; //glIsEnabled(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

               /* Enable arrays */
               glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
               glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
               if (qobj->textureCoords)
               {
                  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
                  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texcoords);
               }
               else
               {
                  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
               }
               if (qobj->normals!=GLU_NONE)
               {
                  glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
                  glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
               }
               else
               {
                  glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
               }
               glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

               switch (qobj->drawStyle)
               {
                  case GLU_FILL:
                       if (!(qobj->textureCoords))
                       {
                          start=1;
                          finish=stacks-1;

                          /* Low end first (j == 0 iteration) */
                          sintemp2=sinCache1b[1];
                          zHigh=cosCache1b[1];

                          switch(qobj->normals)
                          {
                             case GLU_FLAT:
                                  sintemp3=sinCache3b[1];
                                  costemp3=cosCache3b[1];
                                  normals[0][0]=sinCache3a[0]*sinCache3b[0];
                                  normals[0][1]=cosCache3a[0]*sinCache3b[0];
                                  normals[0][2]=cosCache3b[0];
                                  break;
                             case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                  sintemp3=sinCache2b[1];
                                  costemp3=cosCache2b[1];
                                  normals[0][0]=sinCache2a[0]*sinCache2b[0];
                                  normals[0][1]=cosCache2a[0]*sinCache2b[0];
                                  normals[0][2]=cosCache2b[0];
                                  break;
                             default:
                                  break;
                          }

                          vertices[0][0]=0.0f;
                          vertices[0][1]=0.0f;
                          vertices[0][2]=radius;

                          if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                          {
                             for (i=slices; i>=0; i--)
                             {
                                switch(qobj->normals)
                                {
                                   case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                        normals[slices-i+1][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[slices-i+1][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[slices-i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_FLAT:
                                        if (i!=slices)
                                        {
                                           normals[slices-i+1][0]=sinCache3a[i+1]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][1]=cosCache3a[i+1]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                           /* We must add any normal here */
                                           normals[slices-i+1][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_NONE:
                                   default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                vertices[slices-i+1][0]=sintemp2*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[slices-i+1][1]=sintemp2*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[slices-i+1][2]=zHigh;
                             }
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             for (i=0; i<=slices; i++)
                             {
                                switch(qobj->normals)
                                {
                                   case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                        normals[i+1][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_FLAT:
                                        normals[i+1][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_NONE:
                                   default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                vertices[i+1][0]=sintemp2*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i+1][1]=sintemp2*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i+1][2]=zHigh;
                             }
                          }
                          glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (slices+2));

                          /* High end next (j==stacks-1 iteration) */
                          sintemp2=sinCache1b[stacks-1];
                          zHigh=cosCache1b[stacks-1];
                          switch(qobj->normals)
                          {
                             case GLU_FLAT:
                                  sintemp3=sinCache3b[stacks];
                                  costemp3=cosCache3b[stacks];
                                  normals[0][0]=sinCache3a[stacks]*sinCache3b[stacks];
                                  normals[0][1]=cosCache3a[stacks]*sinCache3b[stacks];
                                  normals[0][2]=cosCache3b[stacks];
                                  break;
                             case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                  sintemp3=sinCache2b[stacks-1];
                                  costemp3=cosCache2b[stacks-1];
                                  normals[0][0]=sinCache2a[stacks]*sinCache2b[stacks];
                                  normals[0][1]=cosCache2a[stacks]*sinCache2b[stacks];
                                  normals[0][2]=cosCache2b[stacks];
                                  break;
                             default:
                                  break;
                          }

                          vertices[0][0]=0.0f;
                          vertices[0][1]=0.0f;
                          vertices[0][2]=-radius;

                          if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                          {
                             for (i=0; i<=slices; i++)
                             {
                                switch(qobj->normals)
                                {
                                   case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                        normals[i+1][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_FLAT:
                                        normals[i+1][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_NONE:
                                   default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                vertices[i+1][0]=sintemp2*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i+1][1]=sintemp2*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i+1][2]=zHigh;
                             }
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             for (i=slices; i>=0; i--)
                             {
                                switch(qobj->normals)
                                {
                                   case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                        normals[slices-i+1][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[slices-i+1][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                        normals[slices-i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_FLAT:
                                        if (i!=slices)
                                        {
                                           normals[slices-i+1][0]=sinCache3a[i+1]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][1]=cosCache3a[i+1]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                           normals[slices-i+1][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp3;
                                           normals[slices-i+1][2]=costemp3;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                   case GLU_NONE:
                                   default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                vertices[slices-i+1][0]=sintemp2*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[slices-i+1][1]=sintemp2*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[slices-i+1][2]=zHigh;
                             }
                          }
                          glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (slices+2));
                       }
                       else
                       {
                          start=0;
                          finish=stacks;
                       }

                       for (j=start; j<finish; j++)
                       {
                          zLow=cosCache1b[j];
                          zHigh=cosCache1b[j+1];
                          sintemp1=sinCache1b[j];
                          sintemp2=sinCache1b[j+1];
                          switch(qobj->normals)
                          {
                             case GLU_FLAT:
                                  sintemp4=sinCache3b[j+1];
                                  costemp4=cosCache3b[j+1];
                                  break;
                             case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                  if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                                  {
                                     sintemp3=sinCache2b[j+1];
                                     costemp3=cosCache2b[j+1];
                                     sintemp4=sinCache2b[j];
                                     costemp4=cosCache2b[j];
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                     sintemp3=sinCache2b[j];
                                     costemp3=cosCache2b[j];
                                     sintemp4=sinCache2b[j+1];
                                     costemp4=cosCache2b[j+1];
                                  }
                                  break;
                             default:
                                  break;
                          }
                          for (i=0; i<=slices; i++)
                          {
                             switch(qobj->normals)
                             {
                                case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                     normals[i*2][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                     normals[i*2][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp3;
                                     normals[i*2][2]=costemp3;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_FLAT:
                                     normals[i*2][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp4;
                                     normals[i*2][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp4;
                                     normals[i*2][2]=costemp4;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_NONE:
                                default:
                                     break;
                             }
                             if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                             {
                                if (qobj->textureCoords)
                                {
                                   texcoords[i*2][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                   texcoords[i*2][1]=1-(GLfloat)(j+1)/stacks;
                                }
                                vertices[i*2][0]=sintemp2*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2][1]=sintemp2*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2][2]=zHigh;
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                if (qobj->textureCoords)
                                {
                                   texcoords[i*2][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                   texcoords[i*2][1]=1-(GLfloat)j/stacks;
                                }
                                vertices[i*2][0]=sintemp1*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2][1]=sintemp1*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2][2]=zLow;
                             }
                             switch(qobj->normals)
                             {
                                case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                     normals[i*2+1][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp4;
                                     normals[i*2+1][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp4;
                                     normals[i*2+1][2]=costemp4;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_FLAT:
                                     normals[i*2+1][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp4;
                                     normals[i*2+1][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp4;
                                     normals[i*2+1][2]=costemp4;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_NONE:
                                default:
                                     break;
                             }
                             if (qobj->orientation==GLU_OUTSIDE)
                             {
                                if (qobj->textureCoords)
                                {
                                   texcoords[i*2+1][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                   texcoords[i*2+1][1]=1-(GLfloat)j/stacks;
                                }
                                vertices[i*2+1][0]=sintemp1*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2+1][1]=sintemp1*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2+1][2]=zLow;
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                if (qobj->textureCoords)
                                {
                                   texcoords[i*2+1][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                   texcoords[i*2+1][1]=1-(GLfloat)(j+1)/stacks;
                                }
                                vertices[i*2+1][0]=sintemp2*sinCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2+1][1]=sintemp2*cosCache1a[i];
                                vertices[i*2+1][2]=zHigh;
                             }
                          }
                          glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (slices+1)*2);
                       }
                       break;
                  case GLU_POINT:
                       for (j=0; j<=stacks; j++)
                       {
                          sintemp1=sinCache1b[j];
                          costemp1=cosCache1b[j];
                          switch(qobj->normals)
                          {
                             case GLU_FLAT:
                             case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                  sintemp2=sinCache2b[j];
                                  costemp2=cosCache2b[j];
                                  break;
                             default:
                                  break;
                          }

                          for (i=0; i<slices; i++)
                          {
                             switch(qobj->normals)
                             {
                                case GLU_FLAT:
                                case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                     normals[i][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp2;
                                     normals[i][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp2;
                                     normals[i][2]=costemp2;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_NONE:
                                default:
                                     break;
                             }
                             zLow=j*radius/stacks;
                             if (qobj->textureCoords)
                             {
                                texcoords[i][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                texcoords[i][1]=1-(GLfloat)j/stacks;
                             }
                             vertices[i][0]=sintemp1*sinCache1a[i];
                             vertices[i][1]=sintemp1*cosCache1a[i];
                             vertices[i][2]=costemp1;
                          }
                          glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, slices);
                       }
                       break;
                  case GLU_LINE:
                  case GLU_SILHOUETTE:
                       for (j=1; j<stacks; j++)
                       {
                          sintemp1=sinCache1b[j];
                          costemp1=cosCache1b[j];
                          switch(qobj->normals)
                          {
                             case GLU_FLAT:
                             case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                  sintemp2=sinCache2b[j];
                                  costemp2=cosCache2b[j];
                                  break;
                             default:
                                  break;
                          }

                          for (i=0; i<=slices; i++)
                          {
                             switch(qobj->normals)
                             {
                                case GLU_FLAT:
                                     normals[i][0]=sinCache3a[i]*sintemp2;
                                     normals[i][1]=cosCache3a[i]*sintemp2;
                                     normals[i][2]=costemp2;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                     normals[i][0]=sinCache2a[i]*sintemp2;
                                     normals[i][1]=cosCache2a[i]*sintemp2;
                                     normals[i][2]=costemp2;
                                     break;
                                case GLU_NONE:
                                default:
                                     break;
                             }
                             if (qobj->textureCoords)
                             {
                                texcoords[i][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                texcoords[i][1]=1-(GLfloat)j/stacks;
                             }
                             vertices[i][0]=sintemp1*sinCache1a[i];
                             vertices[i][1]=sintemp1*cosCache1a[i];
                             vertices[i][2]=costemp1;
                          }
                          glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, slices+1);
                       }

                       for (i=0; i<slices; i++)
                       {
                          sintemp1=sinCache1a[i];
                          costemp1=cosCache1a[i];
                          switch(qobj->normals)
                          {
                             case GLU_FLAT:
                             case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                  sintemp2=sinCache2a[i];
                                  costemp2=cosCache2a[i];
                                  break;
                             default:
                                  break;
                          }

                          for (j=0; j<=stacks; j++)
                          {
                             switch(qobj->normals)
                             {
                                case GLU_FLAT:
                                     normals[j][0]=sintemp2*sinCache3b[j];
                                     normals[j][1]=costemp2*sinCache3b[j];
                                     normals[j][2]=cosCache3b[j];
                                     break;
                                case GLU_SMOOTH:
                                     normals[j][0]=sintemp2*sinCache2b[j];
                                     normals[j][1]=costemp2*sinCache2b[j];
                                     normals[j][2]=cosCache2b[j];
                                     break;
                                case GLU_NONE:
                                default:
                                     break;
                             }

                             if (qobj->textureCoords)
                             {
                                texcoords[j][0]=1-(GLfloat)i/slices;
                                texcoords[j][1]=1-(GLfloat)j/stacks;
                             }
                             vertices[j][0]=sintemp1*sinCache1b[j];
                             vertices[j][1]=costemp1*sinCache1b[j];
                             vertices[j][2]=cosCache1b[j];
                          }
                          glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, stacks+1);
                       }
                       break;
                  default:
                       break;
                }

               /* Disable or re-enable arrays */
               if (vertex_enabled)
               {
                  /* Re-enable vertex array */
                  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
               }
               else
               {
                  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
               }

               if (texcoord_enabled)
               {
                  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
               }
               else
               {
                  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
               }

               if (normal_enabled)
               {
                  glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
               }
               else
               {
                  glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
               }

               if (color_enabled)
               {
                  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
               }
               else
               {
                  glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
               }
            }
```

/*end*/

Answer (score 1):

First to answer the question, if you are using ES2, you can try loading all 16x8 textures but I'd say 32 of them is currently maximum on iOS (judging from enumerations for active texture). If you succeed having all the textures you will need to compute which texture to use from the texture coordinates in fragment shader:

```
int verticalTextureCount, horizontalTextureCount; //input tile count
float texCoordX, texCoordY; //input texture coordinates
int textureX = (int)(texCoordX*horizontalTextureCount); //texture to use
int textureY = (int)(texCoordY*verticalTextureCount); //texture to use
texCoordX -= (1.0/horizontalTextureCount)*textureX; //decreas offset
texCoordY -= (1.0/verticalTextureCount)*textureY; //decreas offset
texCoordX *= horizontalTextureCount; //rescale
texCoordY *= verticalTextureCount; //rescale
```

At this point you can write verticalTextureCount*horizontalTextureCount "if statements" using textureX and textureY to determine what texture to use and texCoors to get the texel. That is more or less it.

Second as for the discussion, NO, do not do that. If the texture is too big, it is too big. If I dare to guess I would say you are trying to make an application that has some sort of planet on which you wish to have some extreme zoom function and for that you want some detailed texture. If that is the case or similar, create multiple images that will be used as textures, for instance: Have 1 image on which lays a whole sphere, 4 images with one forth of sphere on each, 16 images... and all this images are of same size like 2048*2048.

Now comes the best part, you need a dynamical system that will load and unload images depending on what you need. If the sphere is zoomed out you only need the 1 whole image and draw as you did before. If you zoom in a lot you need to check what level of texture is most suitable AND check what parts of the sphere are visible so you can load only the textures you need and draw only the parts of the sphere that are visible. This is not an easy task but it is more or less the same principle as in many of the applications where you can see our planet in 3D. It checks in runtime what part of planet are you looking at and at what detail, usually sends request to the server to receive the detailed images if needed and creates the detailed textures to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact, I'm using ES1.1. And to get best display effection, I have to use big picture as texture.

Comment: Instead of passing a texture matrix as a whole texture, I have to modify the drawSphere function which is more difficult to me, for I'm not familiar to OPENGL. 
And I think binding textures frequently (to draw a part of sphere) when drawing isn't a good idea. 
So I want to use texture matrix as a simple and effective method.